# Reputation Banking

Tags: feature-request

Let us say that we have a user who has insufficient amount of reputation so as to put a bounty . Can we have a system or what are the pros and cons of a system which facilitates borrowing and lending of reputation ? The lenders of reputation can be repaid in a certain fixed time interval by the burrower .

Comment: Discussion of same topic on [meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174345/); heavily downvoted, mind you.

Answer (score 5):

People *can* lend rep at zero cost to you. You don't even have to pay them back. How cool is that!  If someone likes your question, they can set a bounty on your question. What you cannot do is *request* or *negotiate* for someone to put a bounty on your question. And that is intentional. We don't want people trying to negotiate for other people's rep points.

You need 75 points to set bounties. 2 answers with 4 upvotes gets you 80 points. 3 questions with 5 upvotes gets you 75 points. I think any user with enough useful knowledge to contribute to the site can put in a little effort an earn the reputation to be able to set bounties.

If you need a quick answer and it's your first time using the site, you may think bounties are some fast way to encourage a response. But it's not like bounties have some elite status or something. A bounty is just an extra incentive to answer, but many people answer questions just because they are interested in the topic, or they like to answer, or many reasons not related to earning points. So really you don't *need* a bounty in order to get a good response. That's why SE is awesome. Anyone can ask and answer without having rep.